# Feedback of test runs in Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

If I run a bunch of tests inside Testcafe, it may need a couple of times. Is it possible to add a function/callback to get the current test/step that Testcafe is processing?

Answer (score 2):

Such information is available in custom reporter plugins. If you want to know which test is executed at this moment, you need to implement a custom reporter and plug it to TestCafe.
See more information related to a custom reporter's implementation [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/).

Comment: Yes this I read, but I already used he allure reporter. I do not think it is possible to use two, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  See how to specify multiple reporters [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#using-multiple-reporters)

Comment: Im very confused. After creating the own reporter I just got: { GeneralError: Multiple reporters attempting to write to stdout: "spec, uistatusreporter, allure". Only one reporter can write to stdout.

Comment: Could you please describe how you set up these reporters?

Comment: Adding a dedicated output will cause an illegal operation. illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/ingofoerster/Downloads/development/speedmaster/allure/allure-report'

Comment: .reporter(['spec', {
    name: 'uistatusreporter'
}, {
    name: 'allure’,__basedir + '/allure/allure-report'
}])

Comment: The issue I do not understand is, that the allure reporter do not write to stdout. But also do not write to a default location. If allure will use stdout it have to write to console, too. But it do not.

Comment: It looks like I have to give allure reporter a physical file in output, that allure reporter will never use. Maybe a bug.

Comment: TestCafe suggests that a reporter plugin uses the [`write`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/helpers.html#write) helper method. This method writes data into the file or stream specified in the [`output`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#reporter) parameter. If this parameter is not specified, the `write` method outputs data into `stdout`. So, TestCafe considers that all reporters without the output parameters write data into `stdout`.

Comment: The `testacafe-reporter-allure` plugin doesn't call the `write` helper method. It uses its custom logic to write data into a file. That's why the `output` parameter doesn't affect the reporter output.